# Как сделать 2 запроса в 1?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

Есть сайт, нужно на нем авторизоваться с помощью CURL , но для начала нужно получить value из поля (защита от ботов), затем отправить уже данные в форму. Можно как-нибудь такое сделать?

Comment: Вы, наверное, про csrf-токен пишите. Сделать первый запрос, вытащить то поле с странице. Сделать второй запрос с тем полем

Comment: @gil9red есть форма, где https://prnt.sc/1qbtdsz recaptchaToken, его нужно отправить с формой вместе, но при каждом запросе он обновляется

Comment: Вытащить из формы все input и составить запрос с ними, скорее всего там будет content-type = multipart/form-data (у меня не открылась ваша ссылка, поэтому точно не скажу)

Comment: @gil9red вот другая ссылка https://i.imgur.com/TxJI1vW.png

Comment: Ну да, собираете все input и формируете словарь по атрибутам name и value. Шлете запрос (скорее всего там post, не увидел начало <form>, там указывается адрес запроса, тип и т.п). Сначала попробуйте в браузере самостоятельно смотря в вкладке сетей какой запрос формируется, после повторяете его кодом

Comment: это не гугл рекапча? гугел капчу спарсить невозможно

Comment: @Jean-Claude это невидимая капча от гугла

Comment: гугел капчу автоматически спарсить невозможно